# Download file as string in python

Tags: python, string, file, python-3.x, download

I want to download a file to python as a string. I have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong, or what else might I do?

```
from urllib import request

webFile = request.urlopen(url).read()
print(webFile)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The following example works.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv'
output = urlopen(url).read()
print(output.decode('utf-8'))
```

Alternatively, you could use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) which provides a more human readable syntax. Keep in mind that requests requires that you install additional dependencies, which may increase the complexity of deploying the application, depending on your production enviornment.

```
import requests

url = 'http://winterolympicsmedals.com/medals.csv'
output = requests.get(url).text
print(output)
```

Comment: The topic was marked as 3.x. This doesn't seem to work in 3.x.

Comment: Weird... pretty sure something changed with the question.. or maybe it worked on early versions of Python (since this is from 2013).

Comment: Both example blocks work on my macOS system with Python 3.8.2.

Answer (score 7):

In Python3.x, using package 'urllib' like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

data = urlopen('http://www.google.com').read() #bytes
body = data.decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another good library for this is http://docs.python-requests.org

It's not built-in, but I've found it to be much more usable than urllib*.